# Select a Placeholder in a Notebook?

Tags: replacement, version-10

How might I select the 1st Placeholder in a Notebook?

```
SelectionMove
```

Has no option.

```
Button["Click Here",
 NotebookWrite[
   InputNotebook[],
   ToBoxes[Unevaluated@Sum[Placeholder[m ], {t, 1, n}]],
   Placeholder];
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in version 10.0.0 under Windows:

```
NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "\[Placeholder]"]
```

Since:

> `NotebookFind[obj,data]`
>   sets the current selection in the specified notebook object to be the next occurrence of data.

This must be placed at the top of the Notebook when it is run.

Comment: It is a named Placeholder.  But I believe I see.

Comment: @Liam I don't understand your comment.  What do you mean?  Were you *not* referring to `\[Placeholder]` as generated with `Placeholder[]`?

Comment: I am.  Posted example.  Version doesn't work currently.